# Sqoop import query to transfer 1000 random records from a table?

Tags: hadoop, import, sqoop

I have a table of around 100000 records and want to import 1000 random records from that table

can someone help :)

sqoop import \
--connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/userdb \
--username root \
--table emp --m 1

Answer (score 1):

Sqoop is just a tool which transfer the data from mysql to hdfs or hdfs to mysql so there is no any direct command to do this but yes can do it using query like this

query :- 
--query "select * from my_table order by rand() limit 1000 AND \$CONDITIONS" 
it will help you to import or export 1000 rows of the table.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such command for random import but you can limit the record to import only 1000 record using `--query` option. Since you have MySQL database you can use below command:

`sqoop import --connect "$CONNECT_STRING" \
--query "select $source_column from $SOURCE_TABLE_NAME where \$CONDITIONS limit 1000" \
--username $USER_NAME --password $PASSWORD \
--target-dir $TARGET_DIRECTORY_NAME -m 1`

You can also pass any custom query with `--query` option.

Comment: I think we are near to solution inside --query we can write sql query like SELECT * FROM table
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1000 ; correct?

Comment: Yes, you can specify any query using --`query` option.